# How to Filter out data based on Month

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter out all the data which has month 8

I have tried as following

https://jsfiddle.net/n2fypquz/2/

```js
var json = [{
    "empId": 175,
    "Name": "Sai",
    "Sal": 37000,
    "doj": "2019-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "empId": 1751,
    "Name": "Pavan",
    "Sal": 57000,
    "doj": "2019-07-15 00:00:00"
  }
];

var month = '8';

let empData = json.filter(function(mgmtmrktshare) {
  let date = mgmtmrktshare.doj;
  let afterSplit = date.split("-");
  return afterSplit[1] == month;
});

console.log(empData.length)
```

Comment: `var mounth = "08";`

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you are dealing with date values, its always better to use Date object.

**Note:** month in JS starts with `0` so Jan. is 0 and Sept. is 8

```js
var json = [{
    "empId": 175,
    "Name": "Sai",
    "Sal": 37000,
    "doj": "2019-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "empId": 1751,
    "Name": "Pavan",
    "Sal": 57000,
    "doj": "2019-07-15 00:00:00"
  }
];

var month = '8';

let empData = json.filter(({
  doj
}) => (new Date(doj)).getMonth() === month - 1);

console.log(empData.length)
```

Comment: However it really is a typo-type question

Comment: @mplungjan though I agree with `"8"` vs `"08"` typo, in my understanding, string comparison will always lead to issues, hence I'll keep this answer for not. If question is closed, I'll create a fiddle and delete this answer

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the wanted part from the timestamp and get a numerical value, then compare with the month.

```js
var json = [{ empId: 175, Name: "Sai", Sal: 37000, doj: "2019-08-15 00:00:00" }, { empId: 1751, Name: "Pavan", Sal: 57000, doj: "2019-07-15 00:00:00" }],
    month = '8',
    empData = json.filter(({ doj }) => +doj.slice(5, 7) == month);

console.log(empData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: However it really is a typo-type question since the code would have worked with "08"

Answer (score 0):

Just use `parseInt(afterSplit[1],'10')`

```
var json = [{
    "empId": 175,
    "Name": "Sai",
    "Sal": 37000,
    "doj": "2019-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "empId": 1751,
    "Name": "Pavan",
    "Sal": 57000,
    "doj": "2019-07-15 00:00:00"
  }
];

var month = '8';

let empData = json.filter(function(mgmtmrktshare) {
  let date = mgmtmrktshare.doj;
  let afterSplit = date.split("-");
  return parseInt(afterSplit[1], 10) == month;
});

console.log(empData.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```js
var json = [{
    "empId": 175,
    "Name": "Sai",
    "Sal": 37000,
    "doj": "2019-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "empId": 1751,
    "Name": "Pavan",
    "Sal": 57000,
    "doj": "2019-07-15 00:00:00"
  }
];

var month = '8'
function search(month, json){
    for (var i=0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if ((json[i].doj).getMonth() === month - 1) {
            return json[i];
            console.log(json[i])
        }
    }
}
```